# ASP.NET MVC Authorization based on Route Params

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-routing

My site allows people to edit posts. I want people to only edit **their** posts. I'd want an authorization attribute like:

```
[CanEditPost(PostId = Id)]
ActionResult Edit(int Id) { }
```

But it seems like parameters to attributes have to be static, which makes this impossible. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

If you create an attribute that inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute`,

you should be able to access the route parameters by:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    var postId = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Id"];
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: aren't I supposed to override `AuthorizeCore`?

Comment: @CD: So I have to rely on naming conventions? Or else pass in the name of the property?

Comment: @Xodarap: Yes, I can not think of any other option, that how routes work, don't they?

Comment: This is wrong and @Xodarap is right. @CD, rather than just repeating the minimal MSDN text verbatim, look at the MVC source code, particularly the comment in `OnAuthorization`. `AuthorizeCore` is the correct place to override here. Note the comment on thread safety in that method, though!

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: Thanks for the correction. when should `OnAuthorization` be used? @Xodarap: sorry for the wrong comment.

Comment: @CD: As far as I can tell, just about never. In MVC 1 betas, it was the only choice, and authorization was broken when caching was used. I can't think of a good reason to use it today.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: Thanks. I've updated the answer (and my own code too).